# Is there an accepted notation for the $n$th sum/integral of a function?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, summation

I'm working on a thesis in image processing at the moment, and wanted to include a portion concerning the methodology for n dimension images (it will include a fully write up and functioning code for 2D and 3D images), and that would involve taking the $n$th integral of a function of $n$ variables, which in this case would mean the nth sum. For the sum portion, it would something like the sum of $x_1$ from $0$ to $M$, then the sum of $x_1$ from $0$ to $M$, and so on with a total of of $N$ summations.

Is there any sort of widely accepted convention for annotating this, or should I just put something like sum1 of sum2 /dots then the last sum?

edit: specific examples (sorry, didn't know you could use LaTeX here):

2D: $$\sum_{x_1=0}^M \sum_{x_2=0}^M f(x_1,x_2)$$
3D: $$\sum_{x_1=0}^M \sum_{x_2=0}^M \sum_{x_3=0}^M f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$$
Is there a nicer way to express something like:
$$\sum_{x_1=0}^M \sum_{x_2=0}^M \dots \sum_{x_n=0}^M f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please [edit] it to show us an explicit calculation for $2$ and $3$ dimensional images with $M$ small (say $3$).

Comment: you can also make your own notation, similar to what they do when they have the same function being applied many times e.g. $f^n(x)$ as long as you have mentioned that the function is reaplied

Comment: I've seen (and used) multiple summations expressed in the way you have in your final line and I think it's perfectly clear. It would be clear also if you dropped the second summation (over $x_2$) to save space. I find the other answers a bit opaque and I have to think much harder than I do when I read the sums with ellipses in between.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The question was unclear (to me) before the very useful edit.

Comment: We do need a nice symbol to indicate a hypersum of sorts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a convention. Your last version is perfectly clear. If you need to use it more than once then define a short symbol the first time. That could  be as simple as $\sum_0^M f$.

Here are two suggestions each using just a single $\sum$.

$$
\sum_{x \in [1, 2, \ldots, M]^n} f(x)
$$

$$
\sum_{x_i = 0, \ (i = 1, \ldots n)}^M  f(x_i, x_2, \ldots, x_n)
$$

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something glaringly obvious, though that second example looks pretty nice for when I put it in beamer and have limited space.

Comment: I think that the interval brackets should be exchanged for set braces. An improvement would be setting the dimensions $\{1,2,\dots,M\}$ to just $D$

Answer (score 2):

How about something like :
$$\sum_{x_1=0}^M \sum_{x_2=0}^M \dots \sum_{x_n=0}^M f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = \large]_{k=x_0}^{k=x_n}\sum_{x_k=0}^{M_n}f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$

Once you use the above as definition then you can reuse it all over the place, also writing repeated sums was something that caused the the tensor notation to be invented. You might want to look up tensors instead.